# add new same attribute to all objects in existing JSON array node JS

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, attributes

I want to create in node js a function that read all the files (csv format) in a certain directory and put it in a JSON array.
The content of a csv looks like this:

**Name,Quantity,id,company,date**

object 1,-500,123,a,10/9/2015

object 2,-1750,456,b,10/9/2015

object 3,500,0,c,10/10/2015

object 4,200,0,c,10/10/2015

The data from the csv in the JSON array is no problem.

I also want to add a new attribute in the JSON array for all the objects.
The new attribute is called 'Source' and it should be the same for the all the object, called 'supplier'. This differs for each csv file that is read.

The JSON should look like this:

**Name,Quantity,id,company,date, Source**

object 1,-500,123,a,10/9/2015, supplier

object 2,-1750,456,b,10/9/2015, supplier

object 3,500,0,c,10/10/2015, supplier

object 4,200,0,c,10/10/2015, supplier

I tried data.push({'Source': 'supplier'}); but this doesn't work.

Any idea how I should solve this?
Another way is to use a loop to add the new attribute in each object, but I am wondering if that is the most efficient way to solve it.

```
    var fs=require('fs');

    var dir='./load/';
    var data={};

    fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files){
        if (err) throw err;
        var c=0;
        files.forEach(function(file){
            c++;
            fs.readFile(dir+file,'utf-8',function(err,html){
                if (err) throw err;
                data=html;
                **data.push({'Source': 'supplier'});**   //doesn't work
                if (0===--c) {

                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I now try with a loop to add the new attribute, but this doesn't work. The source supplier gives me a error. Also, if I leave that out, all my values are undefined.

```
var fs=require('fs');

var dir='./load/';
var data={};

fs.readdir(dir,function(err,files){
    if (err) throw err;
    var c=0;
    files.forEach(function(file){
        c++;
        fs.readFile(dir+file,'utf-8',function(err,html){
            if (err) throw err;
            data=html;
            if (0===--c) {
                var object=[];
                var database = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    object = data[i];
                    database[i]= {
                        Name: object.Name,
                        Qauntiy: object.Quantity,
                        id: object.id,
                        Company: object.company,
                        date: object.date
                        Source: 'Supplier'      //Error generator
                    }
                }
                console.log(database); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If `data` is an array of objects, then you want `data.forEach(d => d.Source = 'supplier')`, right?

Comment: The array is an array of objects. No way to get around the for loop in each object?

Comment: If you want to touch each element of an array, that is definition of a loop, in one form or another.

Comment: hmm, it seems difficult to do this without the loop.
Ok, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names

async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

  // Perform operation on file here.
  console.log('Processing file ' + file);

  if( file.length > 32 ) {
    console.log('This file name is too long');
    callback('File name too long');
  } else {
    // Do work to process file here
    console.log('File processed');
    callback();
  }
}, function(err){
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```